# ¿Cómo maximizar un split vertical en Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Me encuentro en vim y me gustaría poder expandir uno de mis splits que dividen mi pantalla en dos de forma vertical. Sé que esto se puede lograr en splits horizontales haciendo :

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>

Pero esto no maximiza splits colocados de forma vertical. Sé que podría hacer algo como `Ctr` `W` `1000` `>` pero no se me hace una práctica ideal; también he intentado `Ctr` + `W` + `o` pero cierra mis otros splits y no sé como recuperarlos después de ejecutar este otro comando.

¿Algún consejo?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque trata sobre el uso de un programa arbitrario, no sobre programación.

Comment: No lo haga. La pregunta está etiquetada sobre el tema correcto, se trate o no de programación.

Comment: ¿ Si alguien pregunta sobre inversión en divisas también la dejamos ? Por muchas etiquetas que tenga, la temática del sitio es la que es.

Comment: No la remueva. Esta pregunta `no` fue hecha en temáticas ajenas a la programación. A diferencia de Apps Electron o cualquier otro IDE, Vim es una herramienta fundamental de programación.

Comment: Llevo mas de 20 años trabajando **en** Linux. Se de sobra lo que es `vim`. Es un **editor de texto**. Y encima la pregunta es sobre el uso **normal**, no sobre, por ejemplo, como depurar desde `vim` ni como corregir un *script*. **No pertenece a la temática del sitio**.